# Magit: Autoscan for repositories

Tags: magit

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Magit

If I want to add exist git repo to Magit I add it in variable `magit-repository-directories`

OK. 
But if I have about 20 git repo?
I wan't add it manutaly to Magit. Is it possible Magit to do something like autoscan all git repositories?

Answer (score 2):

Are those repositories scattered all over the place, or do you put your repositories in one or just a few places? If it is the latter, then adding entries like `("~/code/" . 2)` to `magit-repository-directories` will do the trick. This particular entry means "put all directories onto the list that are inside `~/code/` but that are not nested more than two levels deep".